# When too many concurrent connection to MySQL, all Apache-PHP site unable connect to DB

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php, apache-2.4

I'm using RDS from amazon, and tuned the MySQL config to the max.
However, all the site will be stop connecting to the MySQL when the number of connection reached a certain numbers of activities. It's internal network setup, no bandwidth limit and 128GB RAM 32 core Windows Server 2019 Datacenter ECS instance.

The following are my MPM, Httpd.conf, and PHP.ini
Could it be causing by the following configuration?

```
**MPM ConfigurationX**
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    ThreadLimit       2000000
    ThreadsPerChild   2000000
    MaxConnectionsPerChild 0
    MaxRequestsPerChild    0
</IfModule>

**HTTPD2.4 Configuration**
KeepAliveTimeout 180
MaxKeepAliveRequests 10000
Timeout 3200
FcgidMaxRequestLen 51200000
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    MaxConnectionsPerChild 10000000
    ThreadsPerChild 1920
</IfModule>

**PHP7.0 Configuration**
max_execution_time = 1800
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 65536M
```

All calling from the same instance, sharing the same php file initiating the DB connection. Approx 20 connections sharing by 20 sites, opening 200 pages at the same time. The DB will refused the connection. The following is the setting of RDS
innodb_io_capacity 18446744073709551615
innodb_io_capacity_max 4294967295
innodb_read_io_threads 64
innodb_write_io_threads 64

Single RDS instance with 20 DB instances.

PHP code used to initiate the DB instance for site global usage.

```
$db1 = new MySQLi("mysql.abc.com","testing","abc#123","testing",3306);
$db1->query("set names utf8");
unset($db2);
$db2 = new MySQLi("mysql.abc.com","testing","abc#123","testing",3306);
$db2->query("set names utf8");
```

Comment: How many concurrent database connections when performance starts to degrade? How does the code do database access, is there any kind of connection pooling/sharing?

Comment: @JohnMahowald Updated.